How to get IoCs (threat indicators) from Sentinel to Defender for Endpoint
I have scripts running on a cron job that import IoCs to the Defender for Endpoint indicator list (this allows blocking on the endpoints).
We have recently set up a Sentinel instance and it’s pretty easy to add threat intel to Sentinel using connectors. What I would like to do is remove scripts and have all the threat intel flow into Sentinel using the connectors and then send what I need to Defender for blocking.
Considering these are both Microsoft and Cloud platforms I thought this would be easy but I can’t find any info around this.
Has anyone managed to do this?
